# Why mouserover returning all data in callback

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to d3 and currently trying to make a simple line chart using the example provided by Mike Bostock, I have arrieved to the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

    var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .rangeRound([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .rangeRound([height, 0]);

    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date);  })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.close);  });

    d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(d) {
        d.date = parseTime(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
        return d;

    }, function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date;  }));
        y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close;  }));

        g.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
            .select(".domain");

        g.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
            .append("text")
            .attr("fill", "#000")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", "0.71em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Weight (lbs)");

        g.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
            .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
            .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
            .attr("d", line)
            .on("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
    });

    function handleMouseOver(d,i) {
        console.log(d);
        console.log(i);
    }

</script>
```

taken from the following link, I append the link if you want to test with the sample data https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245

The thing is that I want to add a new feature where the user can hover over a part of the line and see what is the value of the data at that moment, what I understand is that I append a new path for each entry in the data, the problem is that when I add a callback to the mouseover event that is suppose to receive as a parameter the data being hover like this:

```
   g.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
            .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
            .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
            .attr("d", line)
            .on("mouseover", handleMouseOver);

    function handleMouseOver(d,i) {
        console.log(d);
        console.log(i);
    }
```

The console.log(d) shows all the data in the data array and not the specific entry in the array that is being hovered, also the index i always gives 0. I want to know what I'm doing wrong or how can I achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the following code for the last append (all else is unchanged; and in that block, I also only changed the lines ending with `//!!`:

```
    g.append("g").selectAll("path").data(data.slice(0, data.length-1)).enter().append("path") //!!
        //.datum(data) //!!
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", function(d,i){return line([data[i], data[i+1]])}) //!!
        .on("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
```

This gives you the correct data and index on mouse over depending on the segment.

Let me dive into the background a little bit:

- `datum` sets the whole data as input for the only instance of path (when checking the DOM in your code above or bl.ocks.org, you'll only see one `<path>` with an insanely long `d`. Which is nice, as the `line()` function can handle this perfectly well. However, you only have ONE element for `mouseover` which doesn't help
- hence, I chose another approach with one `path` for each line segment: My code has an insane number of `<path>`s with a very simple `d` each. However, each path can have a separate mouseover
- to not get overwhelmed, I enclosed all the paths in a g, which doesn't hurt anyway
- I did use the `data()` function. You can read up here for details: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data
- in brief, I tell it to take a selection of all `path` elements currently under `g` (none), and append as many new `path`s as necessary to satisfy the data at hand. Then, for each `path`, apply the next lines
- (this doesn't yet update from a new data, but I want to keep it short)
- and finally, to make it sound, I had to slice the `data` for each input
- (I didn't use ES6 syntax for simplicity now, though ES6 would look nicer and is shorter. Doesn't matter for the result, however)